# How I can Connect to Oracle in ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, oracle, entity-framework

Somebody advised me to use Entity Framework here when I asked this question:
[what is better to build Data layer, Strongly Typed DataSets or Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287407/how-is-better-to-build-data-layer-strongly-typed-datasets-or-classes)

So I read a lot of articles about Entity Framework, I understood that Entity Framework designed to be data-source independent and it will support most of the popular DBMSs.

I Have vs2008 with SP1, and I tried to add **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**, but I couldn't generate the model from Oracle connection, it seems that it's just supporting SQL Server!!

So does it support Oracle or not yet?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider
[Can you use Microsoft Entity Framework with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle)

Comment: it seems that still no solution coming from the Microsoft camp and all the other solutions are commercial or tests that you can't use in production environments.
Anyway thanks for your help...

Answer (score 4):

I also followed multiple tutorials for a model-first entity framework design with Oracle but they all hit the same dead-end.

I was able to connect to my Oracle database through Server Explorer but not when adding an ADO.NET Entity Data Model. All I saw was SQL Server Drivers to choose from.

I eventually ready this [article](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) which stated the following:

> The 32-bit Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio download from http://otn.oracle.com/dotnet is required for Entity Framework design-time features and for other Visual Studio designers such as the TableAdapter Wizard. This NuGet download does not enable design-time tools, only run-time support.

Following the link provided from the article, I downloaded the 32-bit ODAC with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio and this allowed me connect to my Oracle DB.