# MVC2 Entity Model connectivity / Oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have built an ASP.NET classic application that references an Oracle connection to a DBISAM database. i already installed "Oracle Data Provider for .NET"

When I try to connect to the same database in a MVC2 application I do not see any option to select an Oracle Data Source.

I right-click on my Models folder and select Add -> New Item

Choose "Data" on the left panel

Select ADO.NET Entity Data Model than click "Add"

Options were:

```
                 ADO.NET Entity Data Model

                 DataSet

                 LINQ to SQL Classes

                 SQL Server Database

                 XML File

                 XML Schema

                 XSLT File
```

Select "Generate from database..... click "Next"

Here I am presented with a "Choose Your Data Connection" screen. When I click the "New Connection" button I am given a "Choose Data Source" screen.

I am only presented with the following options on the "Choose Data Source" screen:

Microsoft SQL Server

Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5

Microsoft SQL Server Database File

This is where I expected to see ODBC as one of my options. What do I need to do to access ODBC?
Thank You for all help provided!

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework does not support Oracle out of the box, [EFOracleProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318389/how-i-can-connect-to-oracle-in-ado-net-entity-data-model) required or use [NHybernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasesSupportedByNHibernate) instead.